# Draggable text elements with overflow (GSAP)

Tags: gsap

In the Codepen I am trying to make a draggable list of items that contain text. Each item must have `overflow: auto` so that the content can scroll. However, on touch devices in Chrome the pointer event gets caught in the item and it does not drag smoothly.

To replicate, launch in Chrome and enter responsive mode via dev tools. Dragging in between the elements works as expected, but dragging on the elements does not work correctly.

I have tried various draggable options and also laying out without flexbox, but none seem to work. I have also tried toggling a dragging/not-dragging css class that sets overflow:hidden / auto , but that does not have the required effect.

https://codepen.io/motionimaging/pen/efbf92943645bf108e720c9b7b640abd#0

Comment: I believe this was answered in the GreenSock forums: https://greensock.com/forums/topic/17546-draggable-text-elements-with-overflow/

Seems like a Chrome bug, but you can solve this scenario by setting touch-action: none on those elements.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @jack for the answer. More details are here: https://greensock.com/forums/topic/17546-draggable-text-elements-with-overflow/

This does seem to be a browser bug. In my case I fixed it using

```
.item {
  touch-action: pan-y;
}
```

As using `touch-action: none;` results in not being able to scroll the content. `pan-y` limits the movement to the y-axis only, meaning you can drag left to right unhindered.